# Rfkill: Command not found

Tags: debian, wifi

I installed it using aptitude and apt-get but still after purging reinstalling everytime i try to  use rfkill in the terminal it will say command not found.

Comment: i have problems with my Wifi probably a Hardblock therefor i need rfkill.

Comment: But everytime i put $rfkill list in the terminal it simply says that the command is not found

Comment: i looked in the man pages so its not a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got to run it as root.

It does not run, nor it is found as a regular user. It resides in /usr/sbin, that is only searched and used by root. Normally the /usr/sbin/ and /sbin directory house binaries that need to be run with special privileges.

If you defined a sudo user, you can run it as

```
sudo rfkill
```