# Rfkill fails with cannot open nor read /dev/rfkill: no such file or directory and bad file descriptor

Tags: kernel, network-interface, bluetooth

I was trying to activate the bluetooth service in my embedded system (google coral, Mendel Linux), that worked before. I encounter the following (it was not running before but I managed to fix with, temporarily it seems. `Active (running)` is in green):

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-02-20 09:04:28 CET; 2h 45min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 5846 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 797)
   Memory: 712.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─5846 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat

Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill bluetoothd[5846]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill bluetoothd[5846]: Starting SDP server
Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill bluetoothd[5846]: Failed to open RFKILL control device
Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill bluetoothd[5846]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initia
Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill bluetoothd[5846]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 20 09:04:28 silly-quill bluetoothd[5846]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

This led me to start investigating about errors with bluetooth and bluetooth-rfkill related. Still not sure about the SAP driver, but from what I read in [here, debian related bluetooth sap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705326/debian-11-bluetooth-sap-driver-initialization-failed) and [here, sap error on bluetooth service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40839/sap-error-on-bluetooth-service-status) , it seems it's linked to configuring devices for (in this case), bluetooth. In the last one, they recommend adding: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap` to the bluetooth file. I haven't tried it, as the service worked before, and also it still doesn't explain the rfkill behaviour.

```
sudo rfkill list all
rfkill: cannot open /dev/rfkill: No such file or directory
rfkill: cannot read /dev/rfkill: Bad file descriptor
```

[Updating, upgrading](https://superuser.com/questions/1014334/rfkill-command-not-found) or [running as sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269540/rfkill-command-not-found) did not work for me. I learnt about [soft and hard blocks](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181194) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=245668), [this github issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/blueberry/issues/88), and finally, [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/wlan0-is-in-ifconfig-but-rfkill-fails-4175530464/) led me to try modprobe:

```
sudo modprobe rfkill
modprobe: FATAL: Module rfkill not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.98-imx
```

I liked a bit more and found [module not found when I do modprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800731/module-not-found-when-i-do-a-modprobe) so I gave it a try:

```
$ sudo depmod
$ sudo modprobe -r rfkill
modprobe: FATAL: Module rfkill not found.
```

My guess is that there is something wrong with versions of rfkill and my kernel (I am talking with no expertise in kernels at all). I did more research but none led to answer, I'll leave it here but it might not be that relevant: [rfkill cannot open dev rfkill, permission denied](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121609/rfkill-cannot-open-dev-rfkill-permission-denied), [cannot open rfkill in linux, mentioning kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051238/cant-open-rfkill-control-device-no-such-file-or-directory). The Bluetooth service is in compat mode. I thought of adding the Mendel tag, but I do not have enough reputation!

```
uname -a
Linux silly-quill 4.14.98-imx #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 2 02:55:21 UTC 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Whoever supplied the kernel, needs to build it with the rfkill modules enabled.